# trying to add solidus to gemfile but having issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, solidus

this is what im getting when i add solidus to gemfile

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
actionmailer (= 7.0.2.3)

In Gemfile:
rails (~> 7.0.2, >= 7.0.2.3) was resolved to 7.0.2.3, which depends on
actionmailer (= 7.0.2.3)

```
solidus was resolved to 2.5.0.beta1, which depends on
  solidus_core (= 2.5.0.beta1) was resolved to 2.5.0.beta1, which depends on
    actionmailer (~> 5.1.0)
```

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
rails (= 7.0.2.3)

In Gemfile:
rails (~> 7.0.2, >= 7.0.2.3)

```
solidus was resolved to 1.0.0.pre, which depends on
  solidus_core (= 1.0.0.pre) was resolved to 1.0.0.pre, which depends on
    rails (~> 4.2.0)
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/4277

Answer (score 1):

Solidus doesn't yet support rails 7. You'll have to downgrade your version of Rails to 6, or wait for them to finish [adding support](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/pull/4220). You probably also want to be using the latest version of Solidus, which is version 3.1.5.